# Why xargs can't work with tail -f?

Tags: xargs, tail

I want `tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep` it with pattern "arpwatch" and send every line to myself via jabber: `xmpp username@jabber.server` using xargs

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep arpwatch | xargs sendxmpp username@jabber.server
```

no working.

but `tail  /var/log/syslog | grep arpwatch | sendxmpp username@jabber.server`

works well.

I think it's some fundamental thing about `xargs` and `tail -f` that I don't understand.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1038841/how-to-pipe-output-of-active-stream-to-other-commands

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xargs command` tries to collect as many input items (lines, words) as it can to one invocation of the *command*, and it doesn't particularly care about the timing of the input data. If the `tail` process is killed, or `xargs`s buffer get filled, it will run *command* with the arguments it received by then. However, `tail -f` usually doesn't finish by itself, and the limit for command line arguments can be large, so it seems like it doesn't work at all.

You could use `xargs -n1` to have it pass only one input item at a time to *command*, but you'll be hit by the fact that `xargs` uses whitespace to split the input into items, so an input line of `foo bar` would cause the command to run twice.

With GNU xargs, `xargs -n1 -d '\n'` should do what you want: run *command* once for each input line, with the full line passed as a single argument.

Try, e.g. with and without the `-d` and `-n` and make note of the output timing:

```
$ ( echo "123 456"; sleep 1; echo foo; sleep 1; echo doo ) | xargs -d '\n' -n1 printf ':%s\n'
```

`xargs -L 1` would also work, but it will still split the line to separate arguments, instead of passing the whole line as one argument.

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful.

Answer (score 6):

`grep` has the option `--line-buffered` to output each line immediately instead of waiting for more input.

For `xargs`, as suggested by @ikkachu, you need to separate by newlines instead of spaces. You can use `xargs -L` for that.

This should work:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog \
  | grep --line-buffered arpwatch \
  | xargs -L1 sendxmpp username@jabber.server
```

Comment: `-L1` is not to separate by newline, but to run one command per line with as many words as there are on the line as separate arguments; IOW, space, tab (and other whitespace depending on the implementation) and quotes/blackslash are still used as delimiters. To split by newline, you need either GNU's `-d '\n'` or escape all other blanks and quoting operators supported by `xargs`. Or with some implementations that suport `-0` and not `-d`, use `tr '\n' '\0'` in combination with `xargs -0`.