# Inconsistent behaviour when piping output of Tail into Xargs through an editing command

Tags: awk, sed, xargs, tail, tr

I'm giving in to asking the SE spirits for assistance. I will expand in detail below, but I've boiled the inconsistency down to these 3 lines. I am trying to grep a string in between single quotes (which is inside square brackets) and use it with xargs command:

A) This works:

```
tail -f -n 1 /var/log/a.log | grep --line-buffered -Po "\'(.*?)\'" | tr -d \'
```

B) This works:

```
tail -f -n 1 /var/log/a.log | grep --line-buffered -Po "\'(.*?)\'" | xargs -t -n1 -d '\n' echo
```

C) This doesnt:

```
tail -f -n 1 /var/log/a.log | grep --line-buffered -Po "\'(.*?)\'" | tr -d \' | xargs -t -n1 -d'\n' echo
```

Except for one time, it randomly worked when I Ctrl-C'd immediately after. Which tells me it can work, its just getting hung up on something.. Here is the correct output:

```
echo check 
check
```

D) This also works, leading me to deduce it has to be something with Tail, but not helpful for troubleshooting because this means the problem only occurs with Tail:

```
echo "Utterance: ['check']" | grep --line-buffered -Po "\'(.*?)\'" |  tr -d \' | xargs -t -n1 -d '\n' echo
```

..Yet why does it work in B) with Tail, but not with Tr and Xargs in combination. I've seen the same hanging problem (or just no response) with several other string extraction commands I tried, not:

```
cut -d\' -f2
awk -F '"' '{print $2}' (on double quotes)
sed -n " s,[^']*'\([^']*\).*,\1,p "
sed 's/.*\' \(.*\)\'/\1/' (doesnt work escaping single quotes)
```

I understand (slightly) that Xargs is particular about its input from here ([Why xargs can't work with tail -f?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489926/why-xargs-cant-work-with-tail-f)). However, that answer is saying its because of Tail not completing, which is why Ive used the `grep --line-buffered`. It does say it uses all text captured at once and to break that up to use `-n1` and `-d '\n'` to break by lines (versus using `-L 1` which still breaks on whitespace, etc.).

FYI, the -t flag is for verbose (t=talk?) and -p will give interactive confirms..

EDIT1: I was about to post this other oddity that when using Tee to see whats happening it gives 'echo'? But at least @steeldriver's comment worked.

```
tail -f -n 1 /var/log/a.log | grep --line-buffered -Po "\'(.*?)\'" | tr -d \' | tee >/dev/tty | xargs -t -n1 -d '\n' echo
echo
```

Comment: Making `grep` line buffered doesn't mean the whole pipeline will be - try making `tr` line buffered also ex. `stdbuf -oL tr ...`

Comment: @steeldriver yay, that worked! I thought it might be something like that, but I dont quite grasp how it could 'unbuffer' itself after going through buffered grep.. unless the entire command chain is evaluated simultaneously (like quantum superposition?)

Comment: @steeldriver, I added one other small curiousity, but I'm curious, is there a better way to use Grep to extract without outputting the single quotes (the search criteria)? That would avoid the editing commands altogether.. thanks again though, I was hung up on that and the xargs options for hours

Comment: well since your grep apparently supports PCRE, you could use lookarounds I think ex. `grep -Po "(?<=').*?(?=')"`

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, ive used lookarounds before, but didnt remember it leaves out the search criteria. Ill remember that now! Well the concept anyway, the syntax doesnt seem to stick easily, maybe after another couple times of using it will. Thanks for that